# CentOS remove vulnerable packages

Tags: centos, yum, docker

## Introduction

I'm in the process of trying to reduce the number of vulnerabilities with an array of projects associated with our Kubernetes cluster, one of the processes involved is hardening our images. To do so, I'm currently utilising Twistlock to highlight all potential vulnerabilities, currently we're trying to remove all high/important & critical vulnerabilities.

According to Twistlock's dashboard, one of the packages that's vulnerable is associated to [sqlite](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2019-5827) & another is associated to [libxml2](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-15412). If I can, I'd also like to remove the vulnerabilities associated with [dbus](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2019-12749), only at this point I'm a little unsure of how to tackle this.

## Process

So far, I'm trying to use a rather primitive process to approach the packages mentioned above, since I'm using CentOS, I'm executing the following commands inside of my dockerfile:

```bsh
## Use the base image. 
FROM base-img

## Utilise root for package management. 
USER root

RUN yum update
RUN yum clean all 
RUN yum remove sqlite
RUN yum remove libxml2

## Run as non root user.
USER jboss

## Now to remove yum.
RUN rpm -e $(rpm -qa '*yum*')

## etc.
```

However, this results in some set of errors, like so, when trying to run our docker build command:

```bsh
...
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
...
```

## Conclusion

I believe that I need some assistance form a Linux guru here? Since the requirements of this project is to ensure that the security is kept to a maximum, we'd really like to remove as many potential threats as possible, I've *pretty much* nailed the application layer already. Now I'm delving into the OS layer & soon I'll be delving into the network layer also, so if anyone can provide any input or guidance on how we could remove such threats, the help would be much appreciated.

### Disclaimer

Unfortunately I'm far from a Linux pro, maybe intermediate at best, so please be patient if I'm missing something. I've also created a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265758/wildfly-application-deployment-issues-related-to-trying-to-resolve-security-vu), only that's more associated with JBoss, if any of you are able to help with that question, help would be much appreciated there also.

Comment: What base image are you using?

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm currently using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly) as my base image.

Comment: Neither sqlite2 nor libxml2 can be removed because they're part of the core OS.  Are you sure that they're vulnerable too?  Keep in mind that the version alone doesn't tell you the whole story, Red Hat backports security fixes to their version they support, see more here: https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting

Comment: @jsbillings I thought that may be the case, I've also tried updating the dependencies to the most recent versions, as you may have guessed, there's not much luck there. I'm saying that they're vulnerable, this is purely based off of what I've read from our Twistlock console/dashboard.

Comment: Does Twistlock give a CVE for why they're vulnerable?  A lot of scanners are dumb and just look at versions.

Comment: @jsbillings for both, yes, while I don't think they're *really* relevant to our applications, we're just trying to remove all possible vulnerabilities. There's [CVE-2017-15412](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-15412) & [CVE-2019-5827](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2019-5827).

Comment: I'd say your approach is a little extreme. First of all, as others said, you have to make sure the vulnerability is directly affecting you. Second, what do you do if you find a vulnerability in the kernel or libc? You uninstall them as well? Security hardening starts with making sure you have your system up to date and that only the necessary services are running, plus the usual security settings regarding user access/RBAC, whatever. Uninstalling packages that (might) have CVEs associated with them is, as I said, a bit much.

Comment: @schaiba I couldn't agree more, a part of the reason why I came here was to verify that I'm applying best practice. To begin with, I thought that I'd just tackle it head on, as I have. The only reason why we're trying to go all out with security is due to the sector of work, we **need** to keep **all** forms of risk to a minimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your process which make it rather difficult (if not intractable).

- You’re starting from a large base image: [`jboss/wildfly`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/dockerfile), based on [`jboss/base-jdk:11`](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/base-jdk/blob/jdk11/Dockerfile), based on [`jboss/base`](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/base/blob/master/Dockerfile), based on `centos:7`. It’s hard to clean up a base image; it’s much easier to start from an image which doesn’t have everything you need, and add to it, than it is to start from an image which has too much, and remove from it. I’m not aware of a nice, minimal image based on CentOS 7; I use [UBI base images](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/31/working-with-red-hat-enterprise-linux-universal-base-images-ubi/) but they might not be appropriate in your context.
- You’re assuming that any CVE reflects a vulnerability that you need to address. A CVE is only a unique identifier; it’s supposed to represent a real vulnerability, but doesn’t always, and even if it does, the vulnerability might not be relevant in your case. For example, [CVE-2017-15412](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-15412) involves XPath extension functions, which means it’s only a *vulnerability* in programs which set up XPath extension functions (and make them accessible to user-controlled input); that’s why you see it listed against Chromium, rather than only `libxml2`. Recent versions of `libxml2` do include a fix which prevents the vulnerability in all dependent programs, but you only need it if you use a vulnerable program in the first place.

Assessing and addressing vulnerabilities takes an enormous amount of resources, which is why most people rely on their providers to do so: typically, that will be whoever produces the distribution on which your base image is built, and whoever builds your base images (if that’s not you), and perhaps whoever hosts your infrastructure. The fact that the vulnerabilities Twistlock is showing in your dashboard haven’t been fixed, even though CentOS 7 is still receiving security updates, suggests that they aren’t considered important enough to be addressed. Of course, that’s no *guarantee* (you get what you pay for), but if you’re not going to blindly trust CentOS, you shouldn’t also blindly trust Twistlock — you need to do your own security assessment.

Comment: Thanks for your input, if anything my manager & I have discussed whether or not it's possible to either build our own base image, in attempt to remove all high+ vulnerabilities. Or alternatively, we've also discussed whether or not we'd like to ignore certain vulnerabilities, as you've stated, with XPath, we doubt that in future we'll be utilising anything that interacts with XPath & user input. At most Selenium with XPath, but that's likely to only be for integration+ testing.